# Convert AnsiString to UnicodeString in Lazarus with FreePascal

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, ansistring

I found similar topics here but none of them had the solution to my question, so I am asking it in a new thread.

Couple of days ago, I changed the format the preferences of an application I am developing is saved, from INI to JSON.

I use the jsonConf unit for this.

A sample of the code I use to save a key-value pair in the file would be like below.

```
Procedure TMyClass.SaveSettings();
var
  c: TJSONConfig;
begin
  c:= TJSONConfig.Create(nil);
  try
    c.Filename:= m_settingsFilePath; 
    c.SetValue('/Systems/CustomName', m_customName);
  finally
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In my code, m_customName is an AnsiString type variable. TJSONConfig.SetValue procedure requires the key and value both to be of UnicodeString type. The application compiles fine, but I get warnings such

```
Warning: Implicit strung type conversion from "AnsiString" to "UnicodeString".
```

Some messages warn saying there is a potential data loss.

Of course I can go and change everything to UnicodeString type but this is too risky. I have't seen any issues so far by ignoring these warnings, but they show up all the time and it might cause issues on a different PC.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just use `string` everywhere?

Comment: Then it would complain 'Warning: Implicit string type conversion from "ShortString" to "UnicodeString"'.

Comment: Why is `string` an alias to `ShortString`? I don't understand why you want to use `ShortString` and `AnsiString`.

Comment: Perhaps that is how it is in Lazarus? I am too new to Lazarus and FreePascal so cannot really answer that question with confidence. 

I am simply declaring a variable as String (previously it was AnsiString), and I get those warnings.

Comment: I think the way forward will be for you to stop doing this in the dark and learn about how strings are handled in FPC. Attempting to move forward without also gaining knowledge isn't likely to be productive.

Comment: I use Lazarus/fpc exclusively but this issue is still muddy for me too. There was a lot of discussion on this. My impression is that current version 1.6 and above handles all this transparently with "string". But the people to ask are really here: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?action=forum or on the mailing list but the mailing list is moslty development related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the warning do an explicit conversion because this way you tell the compiler that you know what you are doing (I hope...). In case of `c.SetValue` the expected type is a Unicodestring (UTF16), `m_customname` should be declared as a `string` unless there is good reason to do differently (see below), otherwise you may trigger unwanted internal conversions.

A `string` in Lazarus is UTF8-encoded, by default. Therefore, you can use the function `UTF8Decode()` for the conversion from UTF8 to Unicode, or `UTF8ToUTF16()` (unit *LazUtf8*).

```
var
  c: TJSONConfig;
  m_customName: String;
...
  c.SetValue('/Systems/CustomName', UTF8Decode(m_customName));
```

You say above that the key-value pairs are in a file. Then the conversion depends on the encoding of the file. Normally I open the file in a good text editor and find the encoding somewhere - NotePad++, for example, displays the name of the encoding in the right corner of the statusbar. Suppose the encoding is that of codepage 1252 (Latin-1). These are ansistrings, therefore, you can declare the strings read from the file as `ansistring`. Because UTF8 strings are so common in Lazarus there is no direct conversion from ansistring to Unicode, and you must convert to UTF8 first. In the unit *lconvencoding* you find many conversion routines between various encodings. Select CP1252toUTF8() to go to UTF8, and then apply UTF8Decode() to finally get Unicode.

```
var
  c: TJSONConfig;
  m_customName: ansistring;
...
  c.SetValue('/Systems/CustomName', UTF8Decode(CP1252ToUTF8(m_customName)));
```

The FreePascal compiler 3.0 can handle many of these conversions automatically using strings with predefined encodings. But I think explicit conversions are very clear to see what is happening. And fpc3.0 still emits the warnings which you want to avoid...

Comment: Thank you. What I wanted to know was in this answer.

    Explicitly convert AnsiString to UnicodeString: UTF8Decode
    Explicitly convert UnicodeString to AnsiString: UTF8Encode

Kind of feel that the names should be other way round. I am not complaining.

Comment: I feel with you - never got lucky with these names and prefer the UTF8ToUTF16 and UTF16ToUTF8 functions.